# Small capitals with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, small-caps

It looks like a bug has been introduced in the last update of `biblatex`. The code below used to output author's family names in small capitals, but not anymore?

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Lame,
  title={Théorie mathématique de l'élasticité des corps solides},
  author={Lamé, Gabriel},
  year={1852},
  publisher={Bachelier},
  address={Paris}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}} % IMPORTANT LINE TO BE COMMENTED

\begin{document} 
PLO \textsc{Plo} plo
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Is this what you observe as well?

```
biblatex.sty    2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex_.sty   2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)
blx-dm.def
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex_.def    
standard.bbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.bbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.cbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
 english.lbx    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not bug but an intentional change in the name format system. You need to use other commands now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Lame,
  title={Théorie mathématique de l'élasticité des corps solides},
  author={Lamé, Gabriel},
  year={1852},
  publisher={Bachelier},
  address={Paris}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}} % IMPORTANT LINE TO BE COMMENTED

\begin{document}
PLO \textsc{Plo} plo
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

(The next version will probably have some fallback system, but I recommend to change to the new commands anyway.)

Comment: hum, nice, where is it documented?

Comment: In release info and docu (search for "mkbibname") (but there is typo in the docu later on and the commands are called "makebibname ...").

Comment: Is there a way to do this for firstname as well?

Comment: @ZachSmith Yes. Search the docu for `\mkbibname`.