# Specific Citation Style in Latex/Bibtex

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib

I need to cite something for school in a very specific style. In the Bibliography it should appear as:

> SURNAME, Name: Title. Subtitle. (X. Edition). Place: Publisher Year.

I already have it down to

> SURNAME, Name, *Title*. Xth Edition. Place: Publisher, Year.

What needs to change is that

1. there should be a colon after the name,
2. the edition number should be in round brackets and
3. preferably the title shouldn't be in italics (although that isn't necessary)

In the footnote it should appear as:

> Surname, Name: Title

I already have:

> SURNAME, *Title*

What needs to change is that

1. the Surname shouldn't be capitalised
2. and it's missing the first name of the author,
3. as well as a colon before the title

I have used:

```
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}} 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} 
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
```

to capitalise the Surname (although I only want that in the Bibliography) and switch first and last name of the authors.
I am using `biblatex` with BibTeX backend and the style `authortitle`.

In full

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {last, first},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  edition = 3,
  address = {a},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\footcite[][15]{key}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You've set both the `biblatex` and the `natbib` tags: Do you use the `biblatex` package, or do you use the `natbib` citation management package? Please advise. Also, should surnames be capitalized in the citation call-outs as well. And, should there be a space, a comma, or some other punctuation mark between "Publisher" and "Year". Finally, what about other entry types, say, `@article` or `@inproceedings`?

Comment: Currently I'm using natbib, but I heard there's better customisation options in biblatex and I'm happy to switch. This specific style of citation needs to be in the footnotesThere should not be any punctuation betwen publisher and Year, but there should be a . at the very end. My bad. This applies only for @book, which is 90% of what I'll be citing, but the other entry types don't really fill my requirements either

Comment: Do please provide (more) information about how entries other than those of type `@book` should be formatted. And, do state how surnames should be formatted in citation call-outs -- assuming that some kind of authoryear-style citation format is called for.

Comment: `@articles` should be formatted as: SURNAME, Name: Title. In:(Where it was published).Year,pages.  I think that covers the things I need, as I very much doubt I'll be using `@inproceedings` in my technical work. I am not a native speaker, could you explain, what a citation call out is? (Is it the one in the footnote, the one in the text or the one at the end?)

Comment: In the text, there needs to be a raised number (and nothing else), in the footnote I'd need [raised number] Surname, Name,: Title, page. The style I've already described needs to be at the end of the document.

Comment: The "citation call-out" is the element in the body of the text that tells the reader that some item is being cited. This could be a number (sometimes in square brackets), a text string of the form "Smith (1999)" , a superscripted ("raised") number , etc. From the information you've provided so far, it looks like your citation call-outs are supposed to be of the superscripted-number type.

Comment: You could start with `biblatex`'s `style=numeric`. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 if you have never worked with `biblatex` and need help to get started. A few things will have to be tweaked, but at least the name thing should be easy: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298630/35864

Comment: @Mico That's exactly it. And that already works. As I understand I'd need to do a \DeclareBibliographyDriver with all the properties in the right order, add punctuation and redefine the author macro to be uppercase. I just have no idea how the syntax works

Comment: @moewe The last thing worked for me, thank you! I've set up biblatex numeric style and my citations do work, the properties are just in the wrong order

Comment: By using `\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}`, I've gotten really close, I just need the colon after the author name and brackets around the edition and proper footnotes (currently I just have a number in the footnote as in ² [2]).

Comment: Also, I'd need 2 kind of citations in the footnote: one, that starts with See and one that doesn't

Comment: Is there a version of the authortitle style with first name and last name? Because I can't find any

Comment: How about you update your question with what you have so far. And then describe in more detail what remains to be changed.

Comment: @moewe good idea, I've done so

Comment: It would be great if you could show us the full code of what you have so far in an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/MWEB (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). That way we can really see what you see at the moment.

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {last, first},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  edition = 3,
  address = {a}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
 \footcite[][15]{key} 
\end{abstract}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If at all possible you should look into using Biber instead of BibTeX. All you need to do with a modern TeX distribution is to run Biber instead of BibTeX, if you use an editor to compile things for you, have a look at [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

The necessary changes can be found in the code below with a short note on what they do. Most of this should already be explained in more details elsewhere on this site.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

% family, given also in citations
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{family-given}

% Small caps only in bibliography
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}}

% colon
\DeclareDelimFormat*{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

% edition in round brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \mkbibparens{%
    \ifinteger{#1}
      {\mkbibordedition{#1}~\bibstring{edition}}
      {#1\isdot}}}

% plain titles
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  year      = {2001},
  title     = {On the Theory of Brontosauruses},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  edition   = 3,
  address   = {Rotterdam},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\footcite[][15]{key}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is perfect. When I run that exact code, I get this error message though: This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: OptimisationIn3DCG.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file OptimisationIn3DCG.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file OptimisationIn3DCG.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file OptimisationIn3DCG.aux (There were 3 error messages). I am using Texmaker. I had the same problem earlier, that's why I switched to bibtex in the first place (it works just fine there).

Comment: @FelixWindisch Yes, with that code you need to run Biber instead of BibTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: My biblatex and biber versions are uncompatible... I can probably easily fix that on my own, but is there really a significant drawback to bibtex that makes it worthwhile?

Comment: @FelixWindisch Version incompatibilities should be easily solved by updating your TeX distribution (of course updates are always risky, so if you are very close to a deadline, you may want to defer the update). Biber has been `biblatex`'s default backend for quite some time, and BibTeX is officially considered a 'legacy' backend now, meaning that it should not be used in new documents any more. Many of `biblatex`'s advanced features can only be used with Biber. In the example here you can get away with not using Biber, but that can not be guaranteed if you want more involved stuff.

Comment: @FelixWindisch From your name I'm guessing you may be German-speaking. In that case Biber has the huge advantage that it can natively deal with Unicode and sorts umlauts properly. BibTeX is ill-equipped to deal with UTF-8 and can only sort ASCII chars properly.

Comment: I am indeed Austrian, but I will write in English, so that shouldn't be an issue. Anyway, thank you ever so much. I also figured out after some weirdness how to actually update MikTex, so it's all working perfectly now.