# Bibliography 3 authors last name, first name, last name, first name and first name last name

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Thank you in advance. So apparently I spent a lot of time editing Citavi styles to find out I cannot use them in LATEX :D

What I need is a bibliography with several authors being in this order:
last name, first name, last name, first name and first name last name
-> instead of "and" an "und" would be great (german)

what I get in Bibliography:
[image: what I get in Bibliography]

what I need it to look like (created with Citavi):

[image: what I need it to look like (created with Citavi)]

Comment: There isn't really enough information to answer this question. Please add a [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/87678) and include your `bibtex` entry for Doi et al (We need to know what fields you are using and this isn't obvious to me as a non-Japanese speaker). To get German, you should use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. There are many questions about smallcaps family names on this site. See for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298632/87678

Comment: But I have to agree with David, in order to give you proper help we need to know more about your document and how you produce your bibliography at the moment, please show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). The bibliography style you are using can strongly influence the 'best' solution.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started, but you'll likely need more things customised. See the comments in the code for explanations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{doi+etal:1978,
  author = {Doi, Yutaka and Sano, Tetsufi and Tanaka, Itsua},
  date = {1978},
  maintitle = {Senkyo seido},
  maintitleaddon = {Das Wahlsystem},
  volume = {10},
  title = {Gendai chihô jichi zenshû},
  location = {Tôkyô},
  publisher = {Gyôsei}
}
\end{filecontents}

% set main language to German
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% use German quotes
\usepackage{csquotes}

% use biblatex authoryear style
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% new titleaddonpunct to use between maintitle and maintitleaddon
\newcommand*{\titleaddonpunct}{\addspace}

% don't emphasise title
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}

% place maintitleaddon in square brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

% use a colon between sortname and title
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

% use small caps for family names
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

% redefine family-given/given-family so only last name is printed as
% given-family (this format is used by default for the sortname in authoryear
% style
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given/given-family}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{listtotal}}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartgiven}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartprefix}}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

% redefine maintitle bibmacro to use \titleaddonpunct between maintitle and
% maintitleaddon
\renewbibmacro*{maintitle}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{maintitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{mainsubtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[maintitle]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{maintitle}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{mainsubtitle}}%
     \setunit{\titleaddonpunct}}% replace \newunit
  \printfield{maintitleaddon}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}` in newer versions I prefer `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}`.

Comment: @moewe, thanks! I wondered about this. I'm a bit behind in some changes.