# How to change the sorting of the last author name in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, sorting

How is it possible to change the name sorting for every last author in the bibliography?

In the following WME it should be **... and N. Tesla** instead of **... and Tesla, N.** 
I'm using biblatex with biber and pdflatex from texlive 2017

Please see this WME:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxnames = 1, maxbibnames=99,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % Reihenfolge beim Namen

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
 author = "Einstein, Albert and Mouse, Mickey and Duck, Donald and Tesla, Nikola ",
 title = "Is reality fun?",
 year = "2201"}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is some random text with a cite \cite{test}. In the biblopgraphy the last author after the \textbf{and} should be sorted Given-Family, i.e. \textit{N. Tesla}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled LaTeX example]

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446731/35864 help?

Comment: Thank you very much, well I searched a lot, but I did not find that question. Thank you very much.

Comment: I only found it because I remembered seeing it a few weeks ago. Would you be OK with closing the question as a duplicate? Your question will remain searchable, so it can help people that think along your lines and search for these keywords.

Comment: yes of course! (I'm just trying to figure out how to do it.)